# why use Resources.Load() in changing the animator controller?

Tags: unity, c#

I wanted to change the `AnimatorController` of a gameobject during runtime, and when I searched for the method, it used this code:

```
animator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load("main/colors/controllercolors/ControllerRED") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
```

My question is, why don't we use a public `AnimatorController` and assign it from the animations folder, then set this equal to the `runtimeAnimatorController` ... Why use `Resources.load`? .. What's wrong with making a public variable rather than loading it from the Resources file?

I am asking cause no one on the forums or any other websites used the public variable method, which suggests that means that the first way is better.

````
public AnimatorController ac;

anim.runtimeAnimatorController = ac;
```
````

Comment: Assigning it in the inspector and getting it from there IMO is the standard way to go. If what you read is old then back in the day Resources were used more often. I assume it was a way for mobile devs on older phones to save the memory until the last moment it's needed.

Comment: "why don't we use a public AnimatorController and assign it from the animations folder , then set this equal to the runtimeAnimatorController" — good question. **Why *don't* you do that?** Why ask Internet randos like us for permission instead of simply doing it the way that makes sense to you and testing to see if it works? You'll find no end of bad advice online — so just because you see a method used a lot doesn't mean it's the best one to use. That same doubt applies to anything we tell you too — bad StackExchange answers happen. The only way to be sure of what works for you is to **test**

Comment: at DMGregory , I did try it from a long time when I first thought of it and it worked , that's why I was curious why almost all of the answers which were more than (4) used this Resources method ,I thought there must be something at play here ,  that made all those people recommend this method, and I had to think that this method were better memory-wise or performance-wise , otherwise why not use the public variable method, I didn't know since I am relatively new to gamedev , that's why I had to ask,, Thanks for answering my question @ DMGregory and at Nikaas

Comment: I saw the people recommending Resources.Load() too and used it. But when I realized how slow and inefficient it was I switched to using serialization to load stuff. Also it's serialization not public. Unity automatically serializes public variables.